# Dynamically set variables in ionic when you do a build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

I want to be able to build or run my ionic app and have it point to the appropriate api.

If I'm running it on my localhost, or if I want it to point to a stage/api or if I want it to point to a prod/api.

I have to imagine there is a way to set some variables when you do a build.

For example 'ionic cordova build ios  --var_name=value'

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: use environment variables. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/injecting-environment-variables-into-the-build/111875 may help

Answer (score 0):

I know a way in android. You have to look for
build.gradle inside platforms/android/app/build.gradle

And add this code:

```
android {
 
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
         espatolero {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appName: "E y L inmobiliaria", launcherName: "Espatolero y Lorenzo", appIcon:"@drawable/icon"]
        
            resValue "string", "images_url", "/espatolero/"
            resValue "string", "primary_color", "#C51112"
            resValue "string", "secondary_color", "#c41011"
            resValue "string", "third_color", "#999"
            resValue "string", "header_home", "true"
            resValue "string", "header_title", "Espatolero & Lorenzo"
            resValue "string", "web_page", "http://www.espatolerolorenzo.com.ar/"
            resValue "string", "has_temporario", "false"
        } 


applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFileName = new File(output.outputFileName, "clientapp-${variant.name}.apk")
        }
    }
```

And then with this plugin you can get the variables:

```
cordova.getAppResources.getResources('images_url').then((images_url) => {
```

Maybe is way for iOS because I remember seen a iOS folder on github of the plugin.